# For Craft CMS, how do I include a category and asset in a GraphQL entry mutation?

Tags: graphql, craftcms

I have been stuck on a mutation graphql query in Craft CMS for an entry. This entry I am trying to create includes a category and asset property. I am not sure how to get the category type or asset type and create it in the entry. I would love some help on this as I cannot find any examples for this from the Craft documentation. Here is my query below:

```
mutation SaveCreation($title: String, $slug: String, $creationProductType: ???(category), $creationImage: ???) {
  save_creations_creations_Entry(title: $title, slug: $slug, creationProductType: ???, creationImage: ???) {
    title
    slug
    creationProductType
    creationImage
    dateCreated @formatDateTime(format: "Y-m-d")
  }
}


{
  "title": "Supports GraphQL Mutations",
  "slug": "supports-mutations",
  "creationProductType": 8971(this is the id of category but do not know if this is correct??),
  "creationImage": {
    "title": "practice image",
    "url": "https://imgur.com/123asfgfgfdg"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so this seemed to work:

```
mutation SaveCreation($title: String, $creationProductType: [Int], $creationImage: [Int]) {
  save_creations_creations_Entry(title: $title, creationProductType: $creationProductType, creationImage: $creationImage) {
    title
    creationProductType {
      id
    }
    creationImage {
      id
    }
    dateCreated @formatDateTime(format: "Y-m-d")
  }
}

{
  "title": "Another Practice dummy",
  "creationProductType": 25800,
  "creationImage": 980
}
```